# Is the gpio readall command compatible with RPi 4?

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, pi-4

It's already a while since I got my Pi 4, but never used the `gpio readall` command until yesterday. I have run into an interesting error.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gpio readall
Oops - unable to determine board type... model: 17
```

Was the `gpio` command already updated to support the new RPi 4, or is my Pi broken? I could read all the pin states and set the pin states from within Python. Is there an alternative to reading the pin states with `gpio readall`?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I have tried flashing new Raspbian image. Still no luck. :(

Comment: You need to upgrade to the last ever version of WiringPi. http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-updated-to-2-52-for-the-raspberry-pi-4b/ see http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-deprecated/ for support information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I am aware it should work provided you download and install the latest version of wiringPi.

http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-updated-to-2-52-for-the-raspberry-pi-4b/

```
cd /tmp
wget https://project-downloads.drogon.net/wiringpi-latest.deb
sudo dpkg -i wiringpi-latest.deb
```

Comment: Is it installable with `apt-get`? Shouldn't the image include the updated version?

Comment: You tell me.  Which version do you get with apt-get?  Is it version 2.52?

Comment: Well, I tried your solution and it has worked perfectly. Thanks! I cannot remember which version I got with `apt-get`.

Comment: ´apt-get´ gets version 2.50, which doesn't seem to work on the 4B. With the 2.52, the problem is solved, though.

Answer (score 1):

Now that wiringpi is deprecated (and requires a download from the author's site to work on the Pi4) the future of the `gpio readall` command is unknown.

I wrote a replacement (which uses pigpiod) - which has the advantage of displaying the ACTUAL programmed GPIO function if changed and can be used remotely (like other `pigpiod` programs). This is simplified, and does not display the confusing wiringpi pin numbers.

If pigpiod is not running run `sudo pigpiod`

gpioread by default displays power pins in colour.

To restore non-coloured output uncomment the 2 lines *# non-coloured output* and comment out *# coloured output*.

Code can be downloaded from https://github.com/Milliways2/gpioread

[image: gpioread screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing recently with the gpiochip interface (included in recent kernels) and realised that the `raspi-gpio` debug tool actually has all the details needed.

`raspi-gpio` should be included in all recent *Raspberry Pi OS*, but if not you can install `raspi-gpio` from the repository

This version of my program (which I call `gpioreadall`) reformats the output of `raspi-gpio` into a user-friendly format similar to the WiringPi `gpio readall`.

This produces output identical to [gpioread](https://github.com/Milliways2/gpioread) but is independent of any other libraries/daemons.
[image]
The code can be downloaded from [GPIOreadall](https://github.com/Milliways2/GPIOreadall)