# Reconfigure pi GPIO default states

Tags: gpio, pi-2, boot

The *default* states (right on boot), on my pi are:

```
+-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 2---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
| BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
+-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
|     |     |    3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
|   2 |   8 |   SDA.1 | ALT0 | 1 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
|   3 |   9 |   SCL.1 | ALT0 | 1 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
|   4 |   7 | GPIO. 7 |   IN | 1 |  7 || 8  | 1 | ALT0 | TxD     | 15  | 14  | << I want to change this 
|     |     |      0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 0 | ALT0 | RxD     | 16  | 15  |    to: V 0, Mode: OUT
|  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |   IN | 0 | 11 || 12 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
|  27 |   2 | GPIO. 2 |   IN | 0 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
|  22 |   3 | GPIO. 3 |   IN | 0 | 15 || 16 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 4 | 4   | 23  |
|     |     |    3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 5 | 5   | 24  |
|  10 |  12 |    MOSI | ALT0 | 0 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
|   9 |  13 |    MISO | ALT0 | 0 | 21 || 22 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 6 | 6   | 25  |
|  11 |  14 |    SCLK | ALT0 | 0 | 23 || 24 | 1 | OUT  | CE0     | 10  | 8   |
|     |     |      0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 1 | OUT  | CE1     | 11  | 7   |
|   0 |  30 |   SDA.0 |   IN | 1 | 27 || 28 | 1 | IN   | SCL.0   | 31  | 1   |
|   5 |  21 | GPIO.21 |   IN | 1 | 29 || 30 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
|   6 |  22 | GPIO.22 |   IN | 1 | 31 || 32 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.26 | 26  | 12  |
|  13 |  23 | GPIO.23 |   IN | 0 | 33 || 34 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
|  19 |  24 | GPIO.24 |   IN | 0 | 35 || 36 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.27 | 27  | 16  |
|  26 |  25 | GPIO.25 |   IN | 0 | 37 || 38 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.28 | 28  | 20  |
|     |     |      0v |      |   | 39 || 40 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.29 | 29  | 21  |
+-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
| BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
+-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 2---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

Is there any way to set LOW output to a specific GPIO pin?
What would I have to do to change `ALT0` with output `1` of BCM 14 into `OUT` with output `LOW`?

I want to configure this at boot level, as soon as the pi is connected to power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `gpio readall` (which is deprecated) **DO NOT** show "default states" - they only show **nominal** usage and **DO NOT** show any user defined changes (although this does show the actual state (High/Low) of pins.

E.g. unless you **specifically** enable serial pins 8,10 are just GPIO inputs.

My program [gpioread](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/106099/8697) reads the  **ACTUAL** state - and there are many ways of determining this e.g `raspi-gpio get`.

The easiest way to set pin state shortly after boot is to use the [gpio config command](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=117&t=208748) in config.txt

NOTE that if you issue conflicting instructions e.g. enabling serial the state is undefined.

Comment: Something like  `gpio=14=op,dl` should work in my case? Thanks!

Comment: Just confirming `gpio=14=op,dl` in `/boot/config.txt` works and will set BCM 14 to  `LOW` **output**.

Comment: How long does it take from the moment the Pi is powered on until BCM 14 is set as `LOW` **output** during the boot, according to `/boot/config.txt`? Is this the same for all the Raspberry Pi versions?