# GPIO pins remain low

Tags: gpio

Im using the command line to set the mode and value of my pins.
When I use,

`gpio allreadall`

I can see that all my pins are set to LOW and INPUT-mode

`gpio -g mode 17 out`

Sets the pin to OUTPUTm but when i use

`gpio -g write 17 high`

The value remains LOW, but how can i set pint 17 to high.

Comment: Basically by following the instructions for WiringPi, but as this is deprecated and unsupported you would be better to use another library and tool.

Answer (score 3):

I can see no evidence that the `gpio` command accepts `high` as an alias for `1` in that command.

Use `gpio -g write 17 1`

Comment: Late to the party, sry! But I have tried that, multiple times, without any success....

Answer (score 0):

WiringPi is deprecated and unsupported.

You can manipulate pins with the included tool `raspi-gpio` e.g.

```
raspi-gpio set 17 op
raspi-gpio set 17 dh
```

[GPIOreadall](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/123749/8697) is a replacement for `gpio readall`.

There are many other libraries e.g. `pigpio` is also included in Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: I don't use that os, I use Ubuntu.