# What is the correct way to access GPIO on RPi?

Tags: gpio, compute-module

I have a brand new Compute Module 4 with Raspberry Pi OS installed. The system is up-to-date, but I cannot read GPIOs or change their state.

```
$ gpio -v
gpio version: 2.52
Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Gordon Henderson
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type: gpio -warranty

Raspberry Pi Details:
  Type: (null), Revision: 00, Memory: 4096MB, Maker: Sony
  * Device tree is enabled.
  *--> Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 Rev 1.0
  * This Raspberry Pi supports user-level GPIO access.
```

If I try to read all gpios I get this error:

```
$ gpio readall
Oops - unable to determine board type... model: 20
```

If I try to change the state of a GPIO it doesn't work

```
$ gpio mode 13 out
$ gpio write 13 1
```

However it does work with the following:

```
echo "13" > /sys/class/gpio/export                    
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio13/direction         
echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio13/value
```

What would be the correct way of using GPIOs on the CM4?

Comment: That gpio utility is part of WiringPi which was deprecated. There is an unofficial mirror https://github.com/WiringPi Are you planning on developing something in a language such as Python or C ? I use the RPi.GPIO library in Python https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/

Comment: I will use the Python Interface then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"What would be the correct way of using GPIOs on the CM4?"

This is strictly opinion based, and thus off topic.

The strict (Linux kernel purist) answer is to use `gpiochip` interface.
Unfortunately this currently provides limited functionality and is a little tardy.

Linux kernel purists consider ANY method of accessing hardware which bypasses the kernel incorrect.

All of the current Pi libraries directly access hardware for performance/functionality. (Joan's `lg` library is a possible exception.)
See [Controlling Raspberry Pi GPIO with c and Python](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117592/8697)

As others have pointed out WiringPi is deprecated, and has no support for CM4; support for Pi4 is limited and incomplete.
However if you want a `gpio readall` equivalent you could try [GPIOreadall](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/123749/8697)

Answer (score 3):

You would probably be better served by using my [lg archive](http://abyz.me.uk/lg/) of programs.  C and Python are supported.

The archive uses the new /dev/gpiochip interface rather than the deprecated sysfs interface used by wiringPi and RPi.GPIO.

lg also has the advantage of being a generic Linux archive and is not tied to the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2):

That gpio utility is part of WiringPi which was deprecated.

There is an unofficial mirror: https://github.com/WiringPi

Are you planning on developing something in a language such as Python or C ?

I use the RPi.GPIO library in Python:
https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/

Another Python library gpiozero simplifies things even more:
https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 1):

In my experience (up to & including the `buster` release), `gpio` works fine on the RPi 4B **if** you install the [WiringPi 2.52 update](http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-updated-to-2-52-for-the-raspberry-pi-4b/) after doing the usual WiringPi installation using `apt-get`.

Comment: WiringPi is obsolete

Comment: @nowox: There are [some that would disagree](https://github.com/WiringPi) with your opinion.

Comment: That’s interesting, I’ll check that!