# wiringpi is missing from bullseye. how do i install it?

Tags: wiringpi

I get the following when trying to install wiring pi on a fresh bullseye image.  Anyone have any way to get it installed?

```
 $ sudo apt-get install wiringpi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package wiringpi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wiringpi is deprecated.

You may be able to install the last release from the author's website which may or may not work on Bullseye.

There are a few alternative libraries.

See [Controlling Raspberry Pi GPIO with c and Python](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/117591/8697)

### Command line tools

[GPIOreadall](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/123749/8697) is a python replacement for the *wiringpi gpio readall* utility.

`raspi-gpio` *designed to help hack / debug GPIO* (included in Raspberry Pi OS) which is used by GPIOreadall also allows command line access. I am unaware of any documentation but `raspi-gpio help` describes usage.

The new gpiochip [libgpiod](https://www.ics.com/blog/gpio-programming-exploring-libgpiod-library) interface has a couple of command line tools. NOTE the Bullseye implementation has a few bugs.

Frankly if you REALLY want to use command line install pigpio (which should be installed in Raspberry Pi OS) and use [pigs](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html).

Comment: OH!  good to know!  are there console alternatives or should I just be using some PL and libraries?

Comment: I did install wiringpi on pi bullseye and it worked like it was expected. I have yet to install wiringpi on Bookworm and soon I am going to try. :)

Answer (score 4):

I was successful with "Rasberry PI OS Bullseye" using this fork:

https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi

```
cd /tmp
wget https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/releases/download/2.61-1/wiringpi-2.61-1-armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i wiringpi-2.61-1-armhf.deb

# Test
sudo gpio -g mode 19 out
sudo gpio -g write 19 1
```

If you have 64 bit you probably need to `wget` "wiringpi-2.61-1-arm64.deb" instead. Also, see https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/releases where you can find all release versions.

Comment: This ought to be the marked answer. Yes, it may be deprecated and have alternatives but OP asked about installing it on Bullseye, not if it was deprecated and what alternatives are available for it. It could be a 3rd party dependency or something else that can't be changed, so the above answer might not help at all in the context of the question. Adding all of that info as *additional context* might make sense, instead.