# Trying to add Gpio22 and Gpio 27 to sys/class/gpio/ in Archlinux (RPI3)

Tags: linux

I'm trying to create gpio22 and gpio27 in  sys/class/gpio/ and enable them, I'm using following command for the same:

```
echo "22" | sudo tee /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "27" | sudo tee /sys/class/gpio/export
```

Using the above commands I'm able to add/configure the pins, But every time I restart the system Gpio22 and Gpio27 disappear from the directory.

Comment: *"But every time I restart the system ..."* -- That's how it is designed to work.  Sysfs is a pseudo-filesystem; sysfs is simply not a permanent filesystem, and is regenerated on each boot.  Learn how to use the newer gpiolib.

Comment: @sawdust thanks for your answer. I'm not using any libraries currently to enable these pins and I don't prefer installing any new libraries onto the system I'm working on. Can you please suggest any other way to permanently enable these pins?

Comment: @sawdust why not make that an answer?

Comment: create a systemd service

Comment: @Droidverine Arch is intended for experts.  You might be better off using the standard Raspberry OS.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to run a program at boot is to edit the file rc.local. This is a file which contains lines of code to be run at boot time. Run `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`. Right before the line `exit 0` in the file paste your code:

```
echo "22" | sudo tee /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "27" | sudo tee /sys/class/gpio/export
```

Save the file by pressing Ctrl-x then Y. Finally press Enter. Your lines of code will run every time at boot. If for some reason this does not work, here are a few other ways of doing it: https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/.

Answer (score 0):

The `gpio` directive allows GPIO pins to be set to specific modes and values at boot time. See https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#gpio

NOTE this is not using the deprecated sysfs interface, so if you want to subsequently change pins you will need another method.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/133252/8697 shows options