# How to install wiringpi on Raspbian

Tags: gpio, pi-4

Hi I am currently preparing my project and I intend to use the gpio and I would like to be able to use the wiringpi library but when I try to installing it with

```
 wget https://project-downloads.drogon.net/wiringpi-latest.deb
 sudo dpkg -i wiringpi-latest.deb
```

this pop up

```
(Reading database ... 96083 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack wiringpi-latest.deb ...
Unpacking wiringpi:armhf (2.52) over (2.52) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wiringpi:armhf:
 wiringpi:armhf depends on libc6.

dpkg: error processing package wiringpi:armhf (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wiringpi:armhf
```

what do I do ?

I am using a RPi 4 with raspbian

EDIT

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                  Version                   Architecture Description
+++-=====================-=========================-============-==============>
ii  libc6:arm64           2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u2 arm64        GNU C Library:>
ii  libc6-dbg:arm64       2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u2 arm64        GNU C Library:>
un  libc6-dbgsym          <none>                    <none>       (no descriptio>
ii  libc6-dev:arm64       2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u2 arm64        GNU C Library:>
un  libc6-dev-arm64-cross <none>                    <none>       (no descriptio>
un  libc6.1-dev           <none>                    <none>       (no descriptio>
lines 1-11/11 (END)
^C
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the output of `cat /etc/os-release` and `dpkg -l '*libc6*'`.

Comment: WiringPi was deprecated in Sept 2019. Raspbian was replaced with RaspiOS in May 2020. So what are you really trying to install.

Comment: @Bodo there you go

Comment: @Dougie I want to start learning a little bit of node to help me in my project and in the tutorial that I found the guy used wiringpi to view and edit gpio parameters

Comment: Forget WiringPi - while it was very good attempting to use is a waste of time. There are plenty of alternatives https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/133251/wiringpi-is-missing-from-bullseye-how-do-i-install-it/133252#133252

Comment: Tsk, tsk - the negativity in some of these comments...

Comment: So - I have been forced to edit my answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question shows different architectures `armhf` vs. `arm64` for the packages.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wiringpi:armhf:
 wiringpi:armhf depends on libc6.
          ^^^^^
```

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                  Version                   Architecture Description
+++-=====================-=========================-============-==============>
ii  libc6:arm64           2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u2 arm64        GNU C Library:>
          ^^^^^
```

Apparently you try to install a 32-bit package on a 64-bit system.

In [Seamus](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/83790/seamus)' [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/137324/139666) there is some useful information which might get overlooked in the longer text telling opinion and explanation about the `wiringpi` project.

> The [wiringpi project has a GitHub site](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi) from which they distribute a [`.deb` file that can be downloaded and installed](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/releases/tag/2.61-1) - the links are at the bottom of the page. There are 2 .deb files - one for 32-bit RPi OS & one for 64-bit OS.

On the Releases page of this GitHub project you can see two versions of the package:

- `wiringpi-2.61-1-arm64.deb`
- `wiringpi-2.61-1-armhf.deb`

Try to purge the `armhf` version and install the `arm64` version.

Answer (score 3):

#### EDIT: `wiringpi` is now in the apt ports repo; so:

```bsh
sudo apt install wiringpi
```

---

Contrary to some **opinions**, `wiringpi` is not a waste of time for everyone. And as long as we are expressing opinions, here's another one to consider: ignore people who make brash pronouncements with no references or supporting documentation. For the record, I have no affiliation with `wiringpi` - past or present; I'm only a user who happens to feel it's not a waste of time.

That out of the way, here's the `wiringpi` story in a nutshell: "Gordon", the original author of `wiringpi`, lost interest in maintaining it a short while ago. Since Gordon's resignation, a team of individuals took on the maintenance of `wiringpi`, and the [wiringpi project has a GitHub site](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi) from which they distribute a [`.deb` file that can be downloaded and installed](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/releases/tag/2.61-1) - the links are at the bottom of the page. There are 2 .deb files - one for 32-bit RPi OS & one for 64-bit OS. Perhaps those who feel `wiringpi` is *deprecated* should reach out to the project team, and let them know?

I'm currently using the 32-bit version on my RPi 3B+ running `bullseye`. I'm neither a frequent, nor a demanding GPIO programmer. Most of my GPIO usage is done through the device tree & its overlays, but when I need to drive or read a pin, `wiringpi` has gotten the job done. I use it for the same reason many people use a software package - it's easy to learn, and it works reliably. In my case the `gpio` utility (part of `wiringpi`) suits me because I prefer `bash` scripting to Python.

Good luck :)

Comment: thank you for your help :) the links were really usefull

Comment: Running `sudo apt install wiringpi` on Bullsye (32bit), I get the following error `Package wiringpi is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source`

Comment: @Wavesailor: That's news... thanks for the update. I did read something recently suggesting that the new team was ready to throw in the towel. However, there *may be* some good news: Another user has forked the WiringPi repo, and seems to be making a significant effort to keep the code moving forward. [Here's the GitHub URL](https://github.com/nuncio-bitis/WiringPi)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
cd /tmp
wget https://project-downloads.drogon.net/wiringpi-latest.deb
sudo dpkg -i wiringpi-latest.deb
```

Then to check it is working:

```
gpio -v
```