# How can I read the current ALT-Mode of a GPIO PIN?

Tags: pi-3b+, rpi.gpio, touchscreen

i have a Hyperpixel 4.0 Touchscreen, which i use one my Raspberry PI 3b+
This Touchscreen is attached directly on the 40 GPIO-Pins and a few Pins have some special Alt-modes.
Out of personal Interest, I want to know more about which GPIO pin has which alt mode.
Is someone able to provide me this information or tell me, how or where i can search the Alt-Mode on my raspberry pi?

Thanks

Comment: https://pinout.xyz tells you all the alt modes. https://pinout.xyz/boards also pinouts for certain boards.

Answer (score 1):

[pigs](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html) (part of the [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) suite) will let you find the current state.

E.g. pigs mg 23 # get mode of GPIO 23

See [mg](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#MG/MODEG)

Also look at [raspi-gpio](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-gpio).

E.g. raspi-gpio get 23

These utilities may be pre-installed on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest is to use `raspi-gpio` e.g.

`raspi-gpio get 1` displays
`GPIO 1: level=1 fsel=3 alt=4 func=RXD2 pull=UP`

`raspi-gpio get 0-27` displays all pins on the header.

I use my program [gpioreadall](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/123749/8697) which lists all pins in an easily readable format.
In addition to displaying the ALT mode it decodes this into the actual function - here "TXD2"

`|   0 | TXD2       | ALT4 | 1 | 27 |`