# Is this an effective way to test GPIO 15?

Tags: uart

I'm working with a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W running Linux raspberrypi 5.15.61-v7+.

Is this a reliable way to establish that I have a non functional GPIO 15?

First, I establish that my test mechanism works by using GPIO 14 to light up an LED that is attached to my breadboard.

```
$ raspi-gpio set 14 op pn dh # Light turns on 
$ raspi-gpio set 14 op pn dl # Light turns off
$ raspi-gpio set 14 op pn dh # Light turns on
$ raspi-gpio get 14
GPIO 14: level=1 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT
```

Next, I then try GPIO 15.

```
raspi-gpio set 15 op pn dh # No light
raspi-gpio set 15 op pn dl # No light
raspi-gpio set 15 op pn dh # No light
raspi-gpio get 15
GPIO 15: level=1 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT
```

To complete the cycle of testing, I move onto GPIO 18.

```
$ raspi-gpio set 18 op pn dh # Light on
$ raspi-gpio set 18 op pn dl # Light off
$ raspi-gpio set 18 op pn dh # Light on
$ raspi-gpio get 18
GPIO 18: level=1 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT
```

Is my test flawed in some way?

Comment: Looks like it is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiringPi used its own eclectic numbering system.
Whatever its justification in 2013 it is best practice to use BCM numbering.

You can set TxD HIGH with

```
raspi-gpio set 14 op pn dh
```

and LOW with

```
raspi-gpio set 14 op pn dl
```

NO need for any libraries or programs with Raspberry Pi OS using the inbuilt `raspi-gpio` utility.

`raspi-gpio help` will show documentation for this utility. e.g.
`raspi-gpio get` will show state of all pins (and has the advantage for showing ACTUAL pin function rather than the static default.

NOTE you may be interested in [GPIOreadall](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/123749/8697) which is a Python program which reformats the `raspi-gpio` output into a format similar to GPIO readall.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the correct nomenclature and just using the command line. So with the command line, I can successfully light an LED with BCM pin 14. But not pin 15. Which makes me think that for my zero 2 w pi - pin 15 is kaput.

Comment: This is not a definitive test. If you have configured serial then GPIO15 would be set as RxD i.e. INPUT. I am unsure if raspi-gpio would override this. To test you would need to disable serial.

Comment: DO NOT put details in Comments. Edit your Question.  raspi-gpio is a far more reliable indicator of pin state than GPIO readall

Answer (score 1):

Check  the GPIO  with pigpio's gpiotest.

https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing

Comment: Right, I forgot to include my results from that test. All pins pass. Still I'm left with the question of - is it reasonable of me to expect my little program to light up GPIO 15 (wPi 16) as I have with all the other GPIO pins that I've tested?