# Canonical means of translating pin identifiers in Python?

Tags: gpio

[Python, at least for now.]

Is there a standard way to translate between the various naming formats for RPi GPIO pins?  *I.e.*, given a pin identifier in one of these forms: `"BOARDn"`, `"WPIn"`, `"GPIO*"`, `(int) n`, and possibly "<*function*>", how can I derive the other forms?

I see that `gpiozero` has methods to translate everything to BCM pin numbers, and function names to physical pin information, but I haven't found anything in any of the libraries I've examined so far that go any farther than that, much less a universal nomenclature-to-nomenclature translation.

Why I want this is irrelevant; my question is whether such functionality is already available somewhere I have yet to look.

[edit]

Example:

```
>>> from gpiozero.pins.data import *
>>> pii=pi_info()
>>> pii.physical_pin('GPIO4')
('J8', 7)
>>> pii.to_gpio('BOARD7')
4
>>> pii.to_gpio('GPIO4')
4
>>> pii.to_gpio('WPI7')
4
>>> pii.physical_pin('WPI7')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/data.py", line 1268, in physical_pin
    raise PinNoPins('no pins can be used for %s' % function)
gpiozero.exc.PinNoPins: no pins can be used for WPI7
```

The BCM pin number is the common destination.  There don't appear to be any methods to translate the BCM pin number to the board number, or the wiringPi number, for example.  What I'm seeking is 'what the the *X* name for pin *Y*' where *X* and *Y* are the various formats.

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking, but my favourite "translation" means is "dictionary"

Comment: @tlfong01: Sure — if the appropriate dictionaries are defined in some library or other, that's *exactly* what I want.  Finding them is my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only 1 naming convention understood by the SoC i.e. BCM.

WiringPi invented its own eclectic numbering (best avoided).
There is code to translate BOARD numbers to BCM - which obviously depends on board. WiringPi & RPi.GPIO do this on **every** call - which strikes me as grossly inefficient (and makes the code confusing).

Most of those who program regularly only use BCM.

If you want to do your own conversion you might find the following helpful.
[GPIOreadall](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/123749/8697)

HEADER is a tuple to convert from BOARD to BCM.

```
HEADER = ('3.3v', '5v', 2, '5v', 3, 'GND', 4, 14, 'GND', 15, 17, 18, 27, 'GND', 22, 23, '3.3v', 24, 10, 'GND', 9, 25, 11, 8, 'GND', 7, 0, 1, 5, 'GND', 6, 12, 13, 'GND', 19, 16, 26, 20, 'GND', 21)
```

It would be trivial to make the reverse (at least for a 40 pin header).

Comment: As I said, why I want this is irrelevant to the question.  Is your answer that no, there is no standard mapping provided by any of the popular libraries?

Comment: none that I am aware of.